# Swap the labels of two buttons by hovering over one of them?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've made two buttons

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>YES</button>
  <button>NO</button>
<div>
```

What I want is, when I hover over the "NO" button, the buttons swap, well, not the buttons, the text swaps.

I could do this with onclick event but there's no such thing as 'onhover'. I want you to show me how you'd do this using only HTML, CSS, and Vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @ksav Why not? It does not look like an X/Y problem to me

Comment: Well, I could be mistaken but it looks like the OP is trying to trick users into clicking on something they don't intend to click on.

Comment: Mind you this is not to trick users, this is just a prank among friends. Anyways I found out how to do it with a little help from the second answer. Here's the codepen link https://codepen.io/shadow-recruit/pen/eYZEMqV?editors=0100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do this using 1 simple Javascript Function**

*Refer my code For much understanding*

```js
function switcher(){
    var y = document.getElementsByClassName("wow");
    for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
      if(y[i].innerHTML=="True")
        y[i].innerHTML="False";
      else
        y[i].innerHTML="True";
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <button class="wow" onmouseover="switcher()"  onmouseout="switcher()">True</button><br><br>
   <button class="wow" onmouseover="switcher()"  onmouseout="switcher()">False</button>
<div>
```

Comment: Your code changes only one button

Comment: No , it works for n number of buttons

Comment: OP wants BOTH buttons to change. Mouse over true and it changes to false AND the false changes to true  - see my answer

Comment: oh sorry , my bad at understanding the problem

Comment: Also inline event handlers are not recommended

Comment: @mplungjan hey , i have updated my code. Is this fine?.And i implemented the inline functions , to make him understand faster. He can change it anytime.

Comment: I would personally use a ternary but yes this works

Comment: @SandrinJoy I got ideas from your first code and found the solution. Check this out https://codepen.io/shadow-recruit/pen/eYZEMqV?editors=0100

Answer (score 2):

Using delegation we can switch each button in one forEach - note I use the [...] spread notation to allow older versions of newer browsers to work too (Edge 16 I am looking at you):

```js
const switchName = e => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.tagName !== "BUTTON") return; // ONLY switch when you touch a button
  [...e.currentTarget.querySelectorAll("button")]
  .forEach(but => but.textContent = but.textContent === "True" ? "False" : "True");
};
document.querySelector(".container").addEventListener("mouseover", switchName)
document.querySelector(".container").addEventListener("mouseout", switchName)
```

```css
div.container {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: teal;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container button {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>True</button>
  <button>False</button>
</div>
```

The CSS is for demonstration purposes only and not part of the answer

Comment: but , this won't switch the text when u shift from one button to another.The switch happens when you enter the parent div. Practically , this couldn't be useful , isn't it?

Comment: @SandrinJoy You are correct. I have updated my answer

Comment: yea and thanks to you too , i understood the problem because of you only